# React JS warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  getting this warning when I run the below code.How can I remove the error?

Thank you.

> Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`. Check the render method of `test`.

```
var test = React.createClass({

getInitialState : function(){
    return {
        number : 10,
        checked: [],
        selected : []
    };
},

componentWillMount : function(){

},

moreAilment : function (){
    var temp = this.state.number + 5;
    this.setState({number:temp});
},

handleChangechk: function (e){
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    var checkedCopy = this.state.checked.slice();
    var selectedCopy = this.state.selected.slice();

    if(value===true) {
            checkedCopy[name] = true;
            selectedCopy [name] = name; }
    else {  
            checkedCopy[name] = false;
            selectedCopy [name] = '';  }

    this.setState({
               checked: checkedCopy,
              selected: selectedCopy });
},


render : function() {

    var ailmentsList = [];
    var selectedList= [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.number; i++) {

        ailmentsList.push(<span ><input type="checkbox" checked={!!this.state.checked[i]}  onChange={(e)=> {this.handleChangechk(e)}} /><span ></span><label> Asthma {i}</label></span>);
        if(this.state.selected[i])
            {
                selectedList.push(this.state.selected[i]); 
            }
    };

    return(
            <div className>
                {selectedList}
            </div>
        );

   }
});
```

Comment: Have you done what the error suggests?

Comment: Yes. I still get the same warning.

Comment: can you create fiddle please?

Comment: if you are using the exact above code, it should not through the warning because you are using checked with onchange event

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked />
</div>
```

Basically, you need to add `defaultChecked` attribute to your checkbox
OR I'm not sure if it will work but lets try can you do onchange this way

```
onChange={this.handleChangechk}
```

instead of `onChange={(e)=> {this.handleChangechk(e)}}`

EDIT: Created Simple example of working Fiddle with Checkbox and Button Toggling state of checkbox
http://jsfiddle.net/yeoman/payugwju/1/

Comment: I tried this as well, I still get the same warning.

Comment: can you try this `defaultChecked={ this.props.checked }`

Comment: Still doesn't work and throws up the same warning, Danish. :(